# Sonarqube upgrade from 5.6.3 to 6.7

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to upgrade our environment from 5.6.3 (LTS) to 6.7 (LTS) version. It is an H2 database which we are currently using for this (POC) so that actual data does not hamper. I have made all the changes as required for Upgrade.

1) Plugin are moved to the new instance

2) H2 db is the same with part of actual data

3) sonar.conf and wrapper.conf have been changed as required.

When I try to start the services on 6.7 version. We have the below value mentioned in sonar.properties.

```
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

When i give the above value for 6.7 I get issue as below:

```
jvm 1    | org.sonar.process.MessageException: a JVM option can't overwrite mand
atory JVM options. The following JVM options defined by property 'sonar.search.j
avaOpts' are invalid: -Xss256k overwrites -Xss1m
jvm 1    | 2017.12.07 10:53:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is
stopped
jvm 1    | 2017.12.07 10:53:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is sto
pped
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: org.sonar.proces
s.MessageException: a JVM option can't overwrite mandatory JVM options. The foll
owing JVM options defined by property 'sonar.search.javaOpts' are invalid: -Xss2
56k overwrites -Xss1m
jvm 1    | org.sonar.process.MessageException: a JVM option can't overwrite mand
atory JVM options. The following JVM options defined by property 'sonar.search.j
avaOpts' are invalid: -Xss256k overwrites -Xss1m
```

When I dont give the value I get the following issue

```
    2017.12.07 10:04:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory E:\Apps\sonarqube-6.7\temp
2017.12.07 10:04:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2017.12.07 10:04:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [E:\Apps\sonarqube-6.7\elasticsearch]: E:\Apps\JRE\8u91\jre\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=E:\Apps\sonarqube-6.7\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=E:\Apps\sonarqube-6.7\temp\conf\es
2017.12.07 10:04:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2017.12.07 10:04:41 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2017.12.07 10:04:41 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2017.12.07 10:04:41 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
```

Let me know in case I am missing something

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please add a question for completeness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, migration on H2 database are **not supported**: the migration won't be triggered in a H2 database. 
You **must** use a dedicated database (Postgresql, Oracle, MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server) to trigger migrations.

Anyway, SonarQube is not starting because you are overwritten a property that it's not authorized anymore. To fix it, just remove -Xss256k on property `sonar.search.javaOpts` from sonar.properties.